# Is this model the Lasso model?

Tags: matlab, optimization, lasso

The following model is about optimization problem with restrictions, The goal is to find the optimal solution of matrix `W`. I want to know that is this model the Lasso model? How to solve it?  Or is there any matlab code/toolbox to solve it? thank you!

[image: The_constraint_equation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not the LASSO model. The constraint $w^T1=1$ and $w^T\mu=\rho$ do not appear in the (canonical) presentation of the LASSO.

However, it is a convex (I assume some positiveness hypothesis of $C$) optimization problem with linear constraints, so most of the convex optimizations problems should do the job.

Comment: can CVX toolbox (convex optimization toolbox) do it? Thank you.

Comment: @user2405694 I am not familiar with cvx but every good optimization toolbox should do the job !

Comment: A few elements in C are negative. Is this model still a convex optimization problem?

Comment: @user2405694 Perhaps. The sign of the elements themselves do not matter. You can find more information about positiveness of matrices here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix